# Where is the code of packages like Magento\ReCaptchaAdminUi on Github?

Tags: magento2, recaptcha, github

I am looking for the code of the above module on GitHub.

I cannot find it in this folder:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module is included in the [security package](https://github.com/magento/security-package), you can find `Magento_ReCaptchaAdminUi` module on
https://github.com/magento/security-package/tree/develop/ReCaptchaAdminUi